# Node.js application gets MongoError connection closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I try to connect with node.js application I get:

> MongoError: connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 ,format = require('util').format;    
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {     
  if(err) throw err;
  var collection = db.collection('student');     
  collection.insert({id:4,name:shyam}, function(err, docs) {              
    collection.count(function(err, count) {         
      console.log(format("count = %s", count));
    });
    // Locate all the entries using find       
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
      console.dir(results);
      // Let's close the db
      db.close();
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Is mongodb running on your local machine?

Comment: No. 
When i try to start service then get the Error 1053:The service did'nt respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. 
Windows could'nt start mongodb service on local computer.

Comment: you need to check monodb logs for these issues

Answer (score 1):

Next time you should write better question.

```
var mongo = require('mongoose');

mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname');

// Connect to mongo
var db = mongo.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
});
```

> learn more about how to connect to MongoDB with node
>   application [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)

Comment: Still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: @shyamji be sure that your mongo server is up

Comment: When i try to start mongodb service is getting issue.

Comment: @shyamji so how you want to connect with the node app if the server is down?

Comment: Windows could'nt start mongodb service on local computer.

Comment: When i try to start service then get the Error 1053:The service did'nt respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: @shyamji so when the server will work the node app should also

Comment: So, Is there any solution to start this service?

Comment: @shyamji run mongod

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongo=require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var assert=require("assert");
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/<database-name>";
mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
assert.equal(null,err);
//insert query
db.close();
});
```

Comment: Actually i am not able to start mongodb service .